# importação PYTHON / PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

Preciso fazer uma importação de um txt e pegar somente alguns caracteres conforme abaixo:

**Texto:**

```
000524WEQWE256243443507AFDAF1698100005891710232323062
```

**Código:**

```
a = (0, 6) = 000524

b = (6, 5) = WEQWE
```

Answer (score 3):

> Só para esclarecer que o titulo da pergunta:
>
> ## importação PYTHON / PANDAS
>
> Significa isso aqui:
>
> ```
> import pandas as pd
> ```
>
> o corpo da pergunta se refere a outro assunto...

Veja se ajuda:

```
texto = "000524WEQWE256243443507AFDAF1698100005891710232323062 "

# apartir do primeiro elemento pegue seis elementos
a = texto[0:6]
print(f'a = {a}')

# apartir do sétimo elemento pegue cinco elementos
b = texto[6:11]
print(f'b = {b}')

#  do nono elemento ao último
c = texto[8:]
print(f'c = {c}')

# do primeiro ao nono elemento
d = texto[:8]
print(f'd = {d}')
```

Código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/WingedGrownFreesoftware